# Does increasing minSdkVersion affects supported devices count (google developer console)

Tags: android, google-play

I just uploaded a new APK to the play store.

I saw that supported devices count decreased from 8000~ to 7000~

I did lots of changes in this version, but the only potentially related change (I guess..) was in gradle file, where I changed the minimum SDK from 15 to 17.

Can it really be the cause of the decrease in device supported count?

I thought that only hardware changes/restrictions in the manifest/gradle affect this.

Can you help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: suppose an android phone running on android 15 so when increased minimum api to 17 then that device is omitted

Comment: By changing the API level you decrease the amount of supported devices. Because... well, devices with lower API cannot use the app anymore....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

```
Controlling Your App's Availability to Devices

[...]
you can restrict your app's availability to devices through Google Play Store based on the following device characteristics:

Device features
Platform version
Screen configuration
```

Comment: "you can restrict" read this as "it will be restricted based on"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does affect the total amount of supported devices. You stopped supporting versions < 17. This means that any phone with an Android version lower than API level 17 is not supported by your app. Which is the cause for the decrease.